# How do you access objects within arrays from JSON in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to loop through some data that I've passed to my JS script from PHP through AJAX.

The data is:

```
history: [
["1h", {
    "number": "8651",
    "event": "lock"
}],
["2h", {
    "number": "16456",
    "event": "edit"
}],
["2h", {
    "number": "90",
    "event": "edit"
}],
]
```

I've parsed the JSON using Jquery with:

```
var responseData = $.parseJSON(data);
history = JSON.parse(responseData.history);
```

But every attempt I've made at trying to access this data has thrown an error, or returned meta info about the object.

```
$.each(history, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

returns:

```
function go()

function back()

function forward()

function pushState()

function replaceState()

11

auto

null
```

How do I access the data?

The reason for parsing twice is that

```
console.log(typeof responseData.history); // 'string'
```

Trying:

```
$.each(responseData.history, function (index, value) {
```

As per gurvinder372's answer gives the error:

```
TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for '(b - 1)' in '[["1h",{"number"...'
```

Comment: You're parsing *twice*.

Comment: You cannot parse JSON which was already parsed.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot edit `window.history` via assignment, so you are iterating `window.history` object, iterate `responseData.history`

```
$.each(responseData.history, function (index, value) {
```

Also, as per your code

```
var responseData = $.parseJSON(data);
```

`responseData` is parsed into an object.

Comment: Good catch with the implicit global assignment.

Comment: @JaredSmith That is the only thing that can explain the output OP gets when he iterate `history`.

Comment: *`responseData` is already a JSON* should probably be *`responseData` is already parsed*

Comment: @connexo That is what I had meant, updated nevertheless.

Comment: I tried switching to `responseData.history` but it seems that it wasn't parsed and is still a string. I've updated the question with the results.

Comment: @Vintage12 In that case use `JSON.parse` on `responseData` as well.